# Can I get the value of a private property with Reflection?

Tags: php, reflection

It doesn't seem to work:

```
$ref = new ReflectionObject($obj);

if($ref->hasProperty('privateProperty')){
  print_r($ref->getProperty('privateProperty'));
}
```

It gets into the IF loop, and then throws an error:

> Property privateProperty does not exist

:|

`$ref = new ReflectionProperty($obj, 'privateProperty')` doesn't work either...

The [documentation page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php) lists a few constants, including `IS_PRIVATE`. How can I ever use that if I can't access a private property lol?

Comment: The IS_PRIVATE and the othe constants are applicable for the getProperties (plural - not getProperty) method

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
class A
{
    private $b = 'c';
}

$obj = new A();

$r = new ReflectionObject($obj);
$p = $r->getProperty('b');
$p->setAccessible(true); // <--- you set the property to public before you read the value

var_dump($p->getValue($obj));
```

**Update**: As of PHP 8.1.0, calling [ReflectionProperty::setAccessible](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php) method has no effect; all properties are accessible by default.

Comment: your example seems to work, but mine doesn't :( Could it be because my class is a child class?

Comment: @Alex: see the difference between them. There's definitely something you've missed

Comment: @Alex: yep, `private` only visible to classes they were created in. But in that case `hasProperty` would return `false`

Comment: that's it :s http://codepad.org/lx8ecZMz ..Is there any way I can get child class properties?

Comment: @Alex: while I check that - explain why you need that

Comment: its kind of complicated to explain.. I have a custom debug function built, in which I'd like to list values of certain properties of certain classes. If it's not possible I'll just create a method that I can call in my debug function which gets that property..

Comment: @Alex: well, I don't see if it's possible to do

Comment: I understand that the question is very old, but I've just wasted some time searching the a way how to access a parent's private property value from the child and reading such incomplete answers, and I hope it would save someone's time:  `$p = $r->getParentClass()->getProperty('b');`

Comment: @AlexandrX very well

Comment: @AlexandrX great! That's what I was looking for for a while! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Please, note that accepted answer will not work if you need to get the value of a private property which **comes from a parent class**.

For this you can rely on [getParentClass method of Reflection API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getparentclass.php).

Also, this is already solved in [this micro-library](https://github.com/ivastly/php-reflection).

More details in [this blog post](https://github.com/ivastly/php-reflection).

Answer (score 2):

`getProperty` throws an exception, not an error. The significance is, you can handle it, and save yourself an `if`:

```
$ref = new ReflectionObject($obj);
$propName = "myProperty";
try {
  $prop = $ref->getProperty($propName);
} catch (ReflectionException $ex) {
  echo "property $propName does not exist";
  //or echo the exception message: echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

To get all private properties, use `$ref->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE);`

Comment: head's up, `IS_PRIVATE` should be `ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE`

Answer (score 2):

In case you need it **without** reflection:

```
public function propertyReader(): Closure
{
    return function &($object, $property) {
        $value = &Closure::bind(function &() use ($property) {
            return $this->$property;
        }, $object, $object)->__invoke();
         return $value;
    };
}
```

and then just use it (in the same class) like this:

```
$object = new SomeObject();
$reader = $this->propertyReader();
$result = &$reader($object, 'some_property');
```

Answer (score 2):

**Without** reflection, one can also do

```php
class SomeHelperClass {
    // Version 1
    public static function getProperty1 (object $object, string $property) {
        return Closure::bind(
            function () use ($property) {
                return $this->$property;
            },
            $object,
            $object
        )();
    }

    // Version 2
    public static function getProperty2 (object $object, string $property) {
        return (
            function () use ($property) {
                return $this->$property;
            }
        )->bindTo(
            $object,
            $object
        )->__invoke();
    }
}
```

and then something like

```php
SomeHelperClass::getProperty1($object, $propertyName)
SomeHelperClass::getProperty2($object, $propertyName)
```

should work.

This is a simplified version of **Nikola Stojiljković**'s answer