# How to access private scoped namespace array data in php?

Tags: php, arrays, api, class, namespaces

Here is the array data:

```
Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\ResourceCollection Object
(
    [previousUri:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\ResourceCollection:private] => 
    [nextUri:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\ResourceCollection:private] => /v2/accounts/REMOVED/transactions?starting_after=REMOVED
    [resources:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\ResourceCollection:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction Object
                (
                    [type:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => send
                    [status:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => completed
                    [amount:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money Object
                        (
                            [amount:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money:private] => -0.00016600
                            [currency:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money:private] => BTC
                        )

                    [nativeAmount:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money Object
                        (
                            [amount:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money:private] => -0.07
                            [currency:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money:private] => USD
                        )

                    [description:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => Your first bitcoin!
                    [fee:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => 
                    [instantExchange:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => 
                    [createdAt:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2016-05-18 21:04:04.000000
                            [timezone_type] => 2
                            [timezone] => Z
                        )

                    [updatedAt:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2016-05-18 21:16:50.000000
                            [timezone_type] => 2
                            [timezone] => Z
                        )

                    [network:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Network Object
                        (
                            [status:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Network:private] => confirmed
                            [hash:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Network:private] => REMOVED
                        )

                    [to:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\BitcoinAddress Object
                        (
                            [address:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\BitcoinAddress:private] => 1BJcYDCMHJ3FAqj8YKbcnNq5xxHcxViD5s
                            [id:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => 
                            [resource:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => bitcoin_address
                            [resourcePath:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => 
                            [rawData:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => 
                        )

                    [from:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => 
                    [address:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => 
                    [application:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => 
                    [buy:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => 
                    [sell:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => 
                    [id:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => REMOVED
                    [resource:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => transaction
                    [resourcePath:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => /v2/accounts/REMOVED/transactions/REMOVED
                    [rawData:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => REMOVED
                            [type] => send
                            [status] => completed
                            [amount] => Array
                                (
                                    [amount] => -0.00016600
                                    [currency] => BTC
                                )

                            [native_amount] => Array
                                (
                                    [amount] => -0.07
                                    [currency] => USD
                                )

                            [description] => Your first bitcoin!
                            [created_at] => 2016-05-18T21:04:04Z
                            [updated_at] => 2016-05-18T21:16:50Z
                            [resource] => transaction
                            [resource_path] => /v2/accounts/REMOVED/transactions/REMOVED
                            [instant_exchange] => 
                            [network] => Array
                                (
                                    [status] => confirmed
                                    [hash] => REMOVED
                                )

                            [to] => Array
                                (
                                    [resource] => bitcoin_address
                                    [address] => 1BJcYDCMHJ3FAqj8YKbcnNq5xxHcxViD5s
                                )

                            [details] => Array
                                (
                                    [title] => Sent bitcoin
                                    [subtitle] => to Bitcoin address
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction Object
                (
                    [type:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => send
                    [status:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => completed
                    [amount:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money Object
                        (
                            [amount:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money:private] => -0.00016600
                            [currency:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money:private] => BTC
                        )

                    [nativeAmount:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money Object
                        (
                            [amount:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money:private] => -0.07
                            [currency:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money:private] => USD
                        )

                    [description:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => Your first bitcoin!
                    [fee:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => 
                    [instantExchange:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => 
                    [createdAt:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2016-05-18 20:41:29.000000
                            [timezone_type] => 2
                            [timezone] => Z
                        )

                    [updatedAt:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2016-05-18 20:45:51.000000
                            [timezone_type] => 2
                            [timezone] => Z
                        )

                    [network:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Network Object
                        (
                            [status:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Network:private] => confirmed
                            [hash:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Network:private] => REMOVED
                        )

                    [to:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\BitcoinAddress Object
                        (
                            [address:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\BitcoinAddress:private] => 1BJcYDCMHJ3FAqj8YKbcnNq5xxHcxViD5s
                            [id:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => 
                            [resource:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => bitcoin_address
                            [resourcePath:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => 
                            [rawData:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => 
                        )

                    [from:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => 
                    [address:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => 
                    [application:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => 
                    [buy:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => 
                    [sell:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private] => 
                    [id:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => REMOVED
                    [resource:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => transaction
                    [resourcePath:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => /v2/accounts/REMOVED/transactions/REMOVED
                    [rawData:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => REMOVED
                            [type] => send
                            [status] => completed
                            [amount] => Array
                                (
                                    [amount] => -0.00016600
                                    [currency] => BTC
                                )

                            [native_amount] => Array
                                (
                                    [amount] => -0.07
                                    [currency] => USD
                                )

                            [description] => Your first bitcoin!
                            [created_at] => 2016-05-18T20:41:29Z
                            [updated_at] => 2016-05-18T20:45:51Z
                            [resource] => transaction
                            [resource_path] => /v2/accounts/REMOVED/transactions/REMOVED
                            [instant_exchange] => 
                            [network] => Array
                                (
                                    [status] => confirmed
                                    [hash] => REMOVED
                                )

                            [to] => Array
                                (
                                    [resource] => bitcoin_address
                                    [address] => 1BJcYDCMHJ3FAqj8YKbcnNq5xxHcxViD5s
                                )

                            [details] => Array
                                (
                                    [title] => Sent bitcoin
                                    [subtitle] => to Bitcoin address
                                )

                        )

                )
```

I am trying to figure out how to access a few of these variables.

For instance, how can I make this happen:

```
$bitcoin_address = [address:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Address:private];
$type = [type:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction:private];
```

I know you can't access private scopes, but is there any way around this? Can I scrape the data if there isn't a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: This might be relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604946/can-i-get-the-value-of-a-private-property-with-reflection

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the best way to access to your data is using `decodeLastResponse` Function.

Its allow to  pull out all the data you need in those arrays.

```
 $address = $client->getAccountAddress($account, $addressId);   
 $transactions = $client->getAddressTransactions($address);
 $transactions = $client->decodeLastResponse();
 echo var_dump($transactions['data']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost all this **private properties** has **public getters** (public methods that allow you to access the private properties).

```
$bitcoinAddresses = [];
$types = [];

foreach ($resourceCollection->all() as $transaction) {
    $bitcoinAddresses[] = $transaction->getTo()->getAddress();
    $types[] = $transaction->getType();
}
```

If you visit [coinbase/coinbase-php](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php) repo, you can see the source code there. There are all the classes you described with all the attributes and methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call function **decodeLastResponse** like this:

```
$addresses = $client->getAccountAddresses($account)    
$addresses = $client->decodeLastResponse();
```