# PHP - Extract specific property info from Array of Objects

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object

I am working on something in Wordpress and need to parse an array of objects and get some specific property information values.

I believe I am having issues be cause the property name has colons in it:

EX: id:DLM_Download_Version:private

The arrays name is **$versions**. This is the value of the array when i use print_r:

```
(
    [0] => DLM_Download_Version Object
        (
            [id:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 208
            [author:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 1
            [download_id:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 196
            [menu_order:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 0
            [latest:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 
            [date:DLM_Download_Version:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2022-03-22 12:48:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )

            [version:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 3
            [download_count:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 0
            [filesize:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 2966739
            [md5:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 
            [sha1:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 
            [sha256:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 
            [crc32b:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 
            [mirrors:DLM_Download_Version:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://wordpress-360386-2306631.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/dlm_uploads/2022/03/STS-SENTIMENT-REPORT-3-21-22.pdf
                )

            [url:DLM_Download_Version:private] => https://wordpress-360386-2306631.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/dlm_uploads/2022/03/STS-SENTIMENT-REPORT-3-21-22.pdf
            [filename:DLM_Download_Version:private] => STS-SENTIMENT-REPORT-3-21-22.pdf
            [filetype:DLM_Download_Version:private] => pdf
        )

    [1] => DLM_Download_Version Object
        (
            [id:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 200
            [author:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 1
            [download_id:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 196
            [menu_order:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 1
            [latest:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 
            [date:DLM_Download_Version:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2022-03-22 12:37:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )

            [version:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 2
            [download_count:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 2
            [filesize:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 3059630
            [md5:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 
            [sha1:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 
            [sha256:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 
            [crc32b:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 
            [mirrors:DLM_Download_Version:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://wordpress-360386-2306631.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/dlm_uploads/2022/03/sts-weekly-sentiment-report-3-14-22.pdf
                )

            [url:DLM_Download_Version:private] => https://wordpress-360386-2306631.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/dlm_uploads/2022/03/sts-weekly-sentiment-report-3-14-22.pdf
            [filename:DLM_Download_Version:private] => sts-weekly-sentiment-report-3-14-22.pdf
            [filetype:DLM_Download_Version:private] => pdf
        )

    [2] => DLM_Download_Version Object
        (
            [id:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 197
            [author:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 1
            [download_id:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 196
            [menu_order:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 2
            [latest:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 
            [date:DLM_Download_Version:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2022-03-22 12:35:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )

            [version:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 1
            [download_count:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 0
            [filesize:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 2648776
            [md5:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 
            [sha1:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 
            [sha256:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 
            [crc32b:DLM_Download_Version:private] => 
            [mirrors:DLM_Download_Version:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://wordpress-360386-2306631.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/dlm_uploads/2022/03/STS-WEEKLY-SENTIMENT-REPORT-3-8-22.pdf
                )

            [url:DLM_Download_Version:private] => https://wordpress-360386-2306631.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/dlm_uploads/2022/03/STS-WEEKLY-SENTIMENT-REPORT-3-8-22.pdf
            [filename:DLM_Download_Version:private] => STS-WEEKLY-SENTIMENT-REPORT-3-8-22.pdf
            [filetype:DLM_Download_Version:private] => pdf
        )

)
```

How can I get just the values of id:DLM_Download_Version:private?

I have tried a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($versions as $version){
echo $version->{'id:DLM_Download_Version:private'}
}
```

which just outputs nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access private scoped namespace array data in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310670/how-to-access-private-scoped-namespace-array-data-in-php)

Comment: Open the source code of the library you're using. There's a `get_id()` method which returns id property. This is what you should do __before__ asking such questions.