# How to get private property from phpUnit Mock object

Tags: php, phpunit

For example I have class

```
class Car
{
   private $color='red';
}
```

After I do mock object

```
$carMock = $this->getMockBuilder(Car::class)->getMock();
```

So now I wanna get **private** property color of Car class

How to do it?!

I can do public method like getCar and it will work, but I wanna look for another way.

I tried use ReflectionClass for it but it was wrong.

Comment: Add a function that returns this value - you cannot access private from outside the class scope, but you can inside it

Comment: First of all: why do you need to get private property? In this context (unit testing?) it shouldn't be necessary

Comment: Try this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604946/can-i-get-the-value-of-a-private-property-with-reflection

Comment: I wanna get private property from **MOCK** object

Answer (score 1):

```
public function setProtectedProperty($object, $property, $value) {
    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($object);
    $reflection_property = $reflection->getProperty($property);
    $reflection_property->setAccessible(true);
    $reflection_property->setValue($object, $value);
}

public function getProtectedProperty($object, $property) {
    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($object);
    $reflection_property = $reflection->getProperty($property);
    $reflection_property->setAccessible(true);
    $reflection_property->getValue($object);
}
```

Comment: For `getProtectedProperty` function, it should return the value at the end.